# In FastReport Export like PDF, Excel, rtf etc. data not all pages are not exporting

Tags: c#, fastreport

When I am exporting data in any format like PDF, Excel, rtf etc. it's exporting is working but not all the pages exporting only 5 pages are exporting. Please help me on that.

```
WebReport webReport = new WebReport()
webReport.Width = Unit.Percentage(100)
string report_path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "FastReport\\");
System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
webReport.Report.Load(report_path + "Transactions.frx");
ViewBag.WebReport = webReport;
```

In Any option is there that allow all pages to export.

Answer (score 2):

@Dhaval Soni, may be you are using demo version of `Fast-Report`. Demo Version of `Fast-Report` only allow 5 pages exporting, better you can go for premium version:https://www.fast-report.com/en/product/fast-report-net/

Comment: hi @sebu i have purchased licence key, but do you know where to add key  ?

Comment: @DhavalSoni, For support from Fast-Report please visit https://www.fast-report.com/en/support/

Comment: Hi @sebu Thank you so much, for help me solve this issue. We solved that issue.